# Time complexity of for loop with a function in it which has complexity of O(n)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested-loops, complexity-theory

> what is the time complexity of the given for loop the complexity of test1() function is O(n) and i think that the time complexity of outer loop is O(logn) so what is the total time complexity i am confused is it be O(nlogn) ?

```
 for(int i=0; i<n;i=i*3){ 
    test1();
 }
```

Comment: Your loop will never terminate.

Answer (score 0):

`i = i * 3` is an interesting increment clause; indeed, this means the loop is `O(logn)`. `n` is not passed to the `test1()` method which makes it rather unlikely that it has `O(n)` performance but perhaps you oversimplified the snippet. Assuming `test1()` is `O(n)`, the entire thing is indeed `O(n log n)`.

Imagine `i = i * 10`, then i grows: 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000 - "count the digits" is exactly what `log n` does - that's a simple way to figure out that `i = i * 3` would have an `O(log n)` performance characteristic.

NB: I answered earlier and misread `i = i * 3` as `i += 3` for some silly reason. That would make the loop `O(n)`. @AndrewS fortunately pointed out I needed to have a closer look in a comment.

Comment: So my assumption is correct about this or not ?

Comment: will it not be endless loop because i is 0 at first and i*3 is always 0?

Comment: Fair enough @ÇiğdemErşepçiler - I think we can safely conclude OP's snippet is to be treated as somewhat carelessly written pseudocode.